# modify price variable

Tags: php

I'm trying to modify a variable from a form.
I want to get rid of any "," but keep the "." while changing it to "%2e"

```
$price = '6,000.65';

//$price = preg_replace('.', '%2e', $price);
$price = urlencode($price);

echo $price;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the exact result from your question:

```
$price = str_replace(',', '', $price);
$price = str_replace('.', '%2e', $price);
echo $price;
```

But why would you urlencode it...? If you want to strip unallowed characters (everything but digits and a dot), use the next function:

```
$price = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]/', '', $price);
// OP requested it...
$price = str_replace('.', '%2e', $price);
echo $price;
```

Alternatively, you can convert the string into a floating point number and use `number_format()` to format it nicely.

```
// note that numbers will be recognised as much as possible, but strings like `1e2`
// will be converted to 100. `1x2` turns into `1` and `x` in `0` You might want
// to apply preg_replace as in the second example
$price = (float)$price;
// convert $price into a string and format it like nnnn.nn
$price = number_format("$price", 2, '.', '');
echo $price;
```

Third option, works in a similar way. `%` is a special character for `sprintf`, marking a conversation specification. `.2` tells it to have two decimals and `f` tells it's a floating point number.

```
$price = sprintf('%.2f', $price);
echo $price;
// printf combines `echo` and `sprintf`, the below code does the same
// except $price is not modified
printf('%.2f', $price);
```

References:

- http://php.net/str-replace
- http://php.net/preg-replace
- http://php.net/number-format
- http://php.net/sprintf
- http://php.net/printf

Comment: You could also do `$price = (float)$price` to get rid of the , and convert it to an actual number rather than a string, and stripping out any non-numeric input in one stroke.

Comment: @Phoenix: I had already been thinking about that, but it won't work for big numbers. I'll include an example.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$newPhrase = str_replace($findWhat, $replaceWith, $searchWhere);
```

so in your case:

```
$newPrice = str_replace(",", "", $price);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$price = '6,000.65';
$price     = str_replace(',','',str_replace('.', '%2e',&$price));

$price = urlencode($price);
```